# Enable sqlite HTML5 in Firefox

Tags: html, sqlite, firefox

I want to use HTML5 sqlite in Firefox but am not able to generate data base using code.

I found that it is not supported by Firefox. Is there any way to use it in firefox.

This works well in chrome (I am using the latest versions of both browsers - Chrome and Firefox). The code below is the code for creating db in sqlite

```
var db = openDatabase("chartDB", "1.0", "this is vendorbuyer database", 200000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not support WebSQL (SQLite in the browser) and will never support it (it has been depreciated by the W3C). You can instead use IndexedDB ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB ) or localStorage ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage ) which are (or will be) supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Having several applications based on webSql, it frustrated me i couldn't run them on Firefox at all. As the [Firefox Add-On for WebSQL](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/html5-websql-for-firefox/) didn't work at all for me, i started on a [WebSQL Polyfill](https://github.com/Philzen/WebSQL-Polyfill).